# Why doesn't my CID (type 11) font work in GS8.61 on Windows

Tags: ghostscript, cjk

I have a customer in Macau that uses Windows EUDC for custom Big5 glyphs.  I used `Fontforge` on Linux to convert the .TTE into a type 11 (CID type 2) font and created a custom `CMap` to map the `Big5` code points to the correct glyph in the font.  This all works fine and dandy in GS8.60 on Windows and GS8.61 - GS8.63 on Linux.  When loading the font in GS8.61 on Windows I get a

> /rangecheck error in /findfont in gs_cidfn.ps.

I've tried to use the `EUDC.TTE` font natively in ghostscript through the `cidfmap` with no luck, `/invalidfont` in `/findfont`.  I'm hesitant to try to contact Ken Lunde, as this appears to be a problem specific to ghostscript.  Does anybody know a workaround?  Has anybody developed a patch so that I'm not reinventing the wheel here?

Edit:  The `/rangecheck` error occurs in the `.buildcidfont` procedure.  The .buildcidfont procedure has not changed from 8.60 to 8.61.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be resolved in GS8.63.  Upgrading the client from 8.61 to 8.63 resolves this issue.